# Crystal Reports Error The database table could not be found proceed to remove this table from report

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, iis, crystal-reports

I have an ERP deployed on the local server. The ERP has more than 200 crystal reports
and it was working fine from last 5 years. But suddenly an error appears in all the crystal reports "The database table "xyz" could not be found proceed to remove this table from report".
I have check all the Tables, Views, Procedures in SQL Server which is working fine there and retrieving in the ERP. Only the problem is with all the reports.  I need some serious help.

Comment: Have there been any updates to the ERP software that may have renamed a database table?  You may want to contact support for your ERP system about this though.  When CR gives you that message its usually because a table used in the report is no longer found in the database.  So you are either connecting to the wrong database from the reports, or the database schema has changed and the table no longer exists or was renamed.

Comment: Check you may be pointing to wrong database

Comment: Maybe is permission issue. Check if the databse user used by reports has permission to access the database and the table.

Comment: Thank you all of you ..the problem is gone. I solved it.